# how to make date into filename?

Tags: python, datetime, choropleth

```
for day in list_of_days:
    # Filter to include only data for each day of week and hour of day
    df_geo = df.copy()

    # Instantiate map object
    map1 = folium.Map(location=[-5.135399, 119.423790], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=12)

    # Plot heatmap
    Choropleth(geo_data=df_geo.__geo_interface__,
               data=df_geo[day],
               key_on='feature.id',
               fill_color='RdPu',
               fill_opacity=0.7,
               legend_name='Daily Covid').add_to(map1)

    # Get day of week string from dow_dict
    date = datetime.strftime(day, "%Y-%m-%d, %A")
    # Add title to heatmap
    title_html = f'''<h3 align="center" style="font-size:20px">
                    <b>{day}</b></h3>
                 '''
    map1.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(title_html))

    embed_map(map1, f'./html_maps/{date}_Covid.html')
```

i tried to make filename into date but got error

> keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

its because your date variable is of type datetime/timestamp. Simply covert to string and it should be fine

```
date = str(date)
```

Comment: it's string 'strftime()', i'm using pyplot and it works but not in folium

Comment: @isfanafely could you add an example of what is in your list_of_days list?

Comment: its a timestamp list_of_days = [2020-03-18 ,2020-03-19, ......] it's row value

Comment: @isfanafely is it definitely the line where you create the filename that is producing that error?

Comment: i think so, i run without that line and it was running properly

Comment: @isfanafely What is the datatype of the elements in list_of_days?

Answer (score 0):

You can just stringify the date variable

```
for day in list_of_days:
    # Filter to include only data for each day of week and hour of day
    df_geo = df.copy()

    # Instantiate map object
    map1 = folium.Map(location=[-5.135399, 119.423790], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=12)

    # Plot heatmap
    Choropleth(geo_data=df_geo.__geo_interface__,
               data=df_geo[day],
               key_on='feature.id',
               fill_color='RdPu',
               fill_opacity=0.7,
               legend_name='Daily Covid').add_to(map1)

    # Get day of week string from dow_dict
    date = str(datetime.strftime(day, "%Y-%m-%d, %A"))
    # Add title to heatmap
    title_html = f'''<h3 align="center" style="font-size:20px">
                    <b>{day}</b></h3>
                 '''
    map1.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(title_html))

    embed_map(map1, f'./html_maps/{date}_Covid.html')
```

Comment: This what what I thought, but apparently this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

the problem is i do not convert the timestamp from before i merge pandas dataframe to geodataframe

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)

list_of_days = df['Date']
```

now i can loop my map, thanks for Emi and Lakpa who tried to help